# XSLT 1.0 - Creating nodes based on attribute values from different nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am having a hard time with the following use case.

Here is the XML:

```
<NodeA>
  <NodeB>
    <Application id="I-555" name="Text1" XorY="Y" />
    <Application id="I-666" name="Text2" XorY="X" />
    <Application id="I-777" name="Text3" XorY="Y" />
    <Application id="I-888" name="Text4" XorY="X" />
  </NodeB>
 </NodeA>

  <NodeD>
   <NodeE>
     <Process id="111" name="Text1" />
     <Process id="222" name="Text2" />
     <Process id="333" name="Text2" />
     <Process id="444" name="Text2" />
   </NodeE>
 </NodeD>

  <Links_between_Process_and_Application>
     <Link_Process_App app_id="I-555" process_id="111" />
     <Link_Process_App app_id="I-666" process_id="222" />
     <Link_Process_App app_id="I-777" process_id="333" />
     <Link_Process_App app_id="I-888" process_id="444" />
 </Links_between_Process_and_Application>
```

What I would like to achieve is to create/tranform a new XML with two new links, between the nodes "Application" and "Process", based on the node `<Links_between_Process_and_Application>`.

The tricky part is (at least for me) is to create two different links/nodes based on the attribute value from `XorY` (pseudocode):

While traversing (for-each) through `<Links_between_Process_and_Application>`
IF(check for the current app_id (e.g. I-555) if @XorY='**X**' in the node "Application")
create <**Link_Process_Application**>
ELSE IF (check for the current app_id (e.g. I-555) if @XorY='**Y**' in the node "Application")
create <**Link_Process_IDP**>

I have written two XSLTs for the transformation and generating these two links (without checking the attribute XorY), because I really don't know how to check the value of an attribute from an different for this use case:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ImportSchemaBase>
            <xsl:for-each select="Links_between_Process_and_Application/Link_Process_App">                  
                    <Link_Process_Application>
                        <SourceKey>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@process_id"/>
                        </SourceKey>
                        <TargetKey>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@app_id"/>
                        </TargetKey>
                    </Link_Process_Application>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ImportSchemaBase>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <ImportSchemaBase>
            <xsl:for-each select="Links_between_Process_and_Application/Link_Process_App">                  
                    <Link_Process_IDP>
                        <SourceKey>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@process_id"/>
                        </SourceKey>
                        <TargetKey>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@app_id"/>
                        </TargetKey>
                    </Link_Process_IDP>  
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ImportSchemaBase>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result should be:

Create Link_Process_IDP because for "app_id=I-555" XorY is Y

```
<Link_Process_IDP>
   <SourceKey>111</SourceKey>
   <TargetKey>I-555</TargetKey>
</Link_Process_IDP>
```

Create Link_Process_Application because for "app_id=I-666" XorY is X

```
<Link_Process_Application>
   <SourceKey>222</SourceKey>
    <TargetKey>I-666</TargetKey>
</Link_Process_Application>
```

Create Link_Process_IDP because for "app_id=I-777" XorY is Y

```
<Link_Process_IDP>
   <SourceKey>333</SourceKey>
    <TargetKey>I-777</TargetKey>
</Link_Process_IDP>
```

Create Link_Process_Application because for "app_id=I-888" XorY is X

```
<Link_Process_Application>
   <SourceKey>444</SourceKey>
    <TargetKey>I-888</TargetKey>
</Link_Process_Application>
```

Thank you a lot and sorry for the long description!

Comment: Where you have ELSEIF, you should also have ELSE. Otherwise the two states are mutually exclusive and there is no need to test for `Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    
  <xsl:key name="app" match="Application" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Link_Process_App"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Link_Process_App[key('app', @app_id)/@XorY = 'X']">
                    <Link_Process_Application>
                        <SourceKey>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@process_id"/>
                        </SourceKey>
                        <TargetKey>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@app_id"/>
                        </TargetKey>
                    </Link_Process_Application>      
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Link_Process_App[key('app', @app_id)/@XorY = 'Y']">
                                        <Link_Process_IDP>
                        <SourceKey>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@process_id"/>
                        </SourceKey>
                        <TargetKey>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@app_id"/>
                        </TargetKey>
                    </Link_Process_IDP>   
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVra/1

Comment: You defined `<xsl:key name="process" match="Process" use="@id"/>` but I don't see where you're using it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, that's true, somehow I initially thought there was a need to cross-reference both type of elements and then I didn't notice I had the key in there without using it. The joys of small screens in a mobile world I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Your input is not XML - it lacks a single root element (and so does your expected output).

Given a well-formed XML input, the task is easy to achieve by using a **key**:

**XML**

```
<root> 
    <NodeA>
        <NodeB>
            <Application id="I-555" name="Text1" XorY="Y" />
            <Application id="I-666" name="Text2" XorY="X" />
            <Application id="I-777" name="Text3" XorY="Y" />
            <Application id="I-888" name="Text4" XorY="X" />
        </NodeB>
    </NodeA>
    <NodeD>
         <NodeE>
             <Process id="111" name="Text1" />
             <Process id="222" name="Text2" />
             <Process id="333" name="Text2" />
             <Process id="444" name="Text2" />
         </NodeE>
    </NodeD>
    <Links_between_Process_and_Application>
         <Link_Process_App app_id="I-555" process_id="111" />
         <Link_Process_App app_id="I-666" process_id="222" />
         <Link_Process_App app_id="I-777" process_id="333" />
         <Link_Process_App app_id="I-888" process_id="444" />
     </Links_between_Process_and_Application>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="app" match="Application" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="Links_between_Process_and_Application/Link_Process_App">
            <xsl:variable name="xory" select="key('app', @app_id)/@XorY" />
            <xsl:variable name="name">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$xory = 'X'">Link_Process_Application</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$xory = 'Y'">Link_Process_IDP</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>SomethingElse</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:element name="{$name}">
                <SourceKey>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@process_id"/>
                </SourceKey>
                <TargetKey>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@app_id"/>
                </TargetKey>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <Link_Process_IDP>
    <SourceKey>111</SourceKey>
    <TargetKey>I-555</TargetKey>
  </Link_Process_IDP>
  <Link_Process_Application>
    <SourceKey>222</SourceKey>
    <TargetKey>I-666</TargetKey>
  </Link_Process_Application>
  <Link_Process_IDP>
    <SourceKey>333</SourceKey>
    <TargetKey>I-777</TargetKey>
  </Link_Process_IDP>
  <Link_Process_Application>
    <SourceKey>444</SourceKey>
    <TargetKey>I-888</TargetKey>
  </Link_Process_Application>
</output>
```

---

Note that if `X` and `Y` are mutually exclusive, you could shorten this further to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="app" match="Application" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="Links_between_Process_and_Application/Link_Process_App">
            <xsl:variable name="name">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="key('app', @app_id)/@XorY = 'X'">Link_Process_Application</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>Link_Process_IDP</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:element name="{$name}">
                <SourceKey>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@process_id"/>
                </SourceKey>
                <TargetKey>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@app_id"/>
                </TargetKey>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```